# A code is failing to work for strings longer than 2

Tags: python

The following Python code works perfectly, but if I un-comment the `print` on line 9, I get strange output. Even worse, if I comment line 8 and un-comment line 9, I get an error message  "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable".

Can someone demystify this? What is going on?

```
def all_perms(the_string):
    all_perm=[]
    if len(the_string)==1:
        return the_string
    else:
        for char in the_string:
            for word in all_perms(the_string.replace(char,'')):
                all_perm.append(char+word)  # line 8
                # print(char+word)          # line 9
        return all_perm
the_string="hey"
all_perms(the_string)
```

Comment: Also, what is odd about it is that if the input string is length of at most 2, un-commenting the print and commenting the line above the print does NOT fail. Only for strings of length 3 or more do we see the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is supposed to return a list of permutations. But in the base case of your recursion, you just return `the_string` instead of a list. It should return a list of one element:

```
if len(the_string) == 1:
    return [the_string]
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/jxPRT3)

If you want to print the strings in the function, add a parameter that distinguishes the top-level call from the recursive ones.

```
def all_perms(the_string, recursing = False):
    all_perm=[]
    if len(the_string)==1:
        return [the_string]
    else:
        for char in the_string:
            for word in all_perms(the_string.replace(char,''), recursing=True):
                all_perm.append(char+word)
                if !recursing:
                    print(char+word)
        return all_perm
the_string="hey"
all_perms(the_string)
```

Comment: Thanks, but note that the fix by putting [the_string] only lets me print out words of length 2. What I really the length 3 permutations of hey:

Comment: Now you have solved half my problem. The list is good! However,   un-commenting the print(char+word)  still outputs shorter strings. Can that be solved too? Ultimately, I want to get rid of the list and print only the strings. note that  the original code also works if you do NOT comment out the print(char+word)

Comment: `char + word` is just part of the result. You don't get the full permutation until  the result is returned back through all the levels of recursion.

Comment: You need to do the printing only in the top-most function of the recursion. If you print in every call, you're just getting partial results.

Comment: Do you understand how this recursive algorithm works? If you do, the answers to your questions should be obvious.

Comment: As a simpler case, what would you expect to see if you wrote a recursive `factorial` function, and printed the number each time it was called?

Comment: correct all_perm=[] is initialized each time we call the the function recursively (so the shorter words are not in all_perm), but char+word gets output 'ed immediately.. OK starting to make sense. Is it impossible to print out ONLY  .the full length permutations? Adding an if statement to print only the longest (using a constant) would be cheating, because you have to change the constant every time you run the code for varying length strings. Any thoughts?

Comment: You need some way to tell the difference between the top-level call and the recursive calls.

Comment: You could add a parameter to the function that you set to `True` when you do the main call, and set to `False` in recursive calls.

Comment: Great! this solves my problem (almost)!, I learned something new "if not recursing:" huh cool, Thanks!  But I the list has to be there. Even when I try not to return the list, I get error message. Wonder if there is a way to get rid of the list if at all. The "print" alone would ve been best.

Comment: You need the list so you can do `for word in ...` with the result of the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Try This One

```
def all_perms(the_string):

    all_perm=['']
    if len(the_string)==1:
        all_perm.append(the_string)
        return all_perm
    else:
        for char in the_string:
            for word in all_perms(the_string.replace(char,'')):
                all_perm.append(char+word)
        return all_perm
the_string="hey"
print(sorted(all_perms(the_string)[1:],key=len))
```

Comment: Thanks, but note that the fix by putting [the_string] only lets me print out words of length AT most 2. What I really the length 3 permutations of hey:

Comment: check this repl link and try executing it u will be able to see the length 3 permutations also:   https://repl.it/repls/WebbedMediumslateblueTinamou